# how to access my domain class variable in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have one domain class.This class contains getters and setters.Now i want to access one variable in JSP.Can you any one suggest me how to access backend variable in JSP.

Comment: Is the variable available in the jsp context? Then it's something like `<%= myvar.getSomething() %>`

Comment: You should not use scriptlets in JSP. It doesn't scale with large code, and is not even more convenient than using correctly beans.

Comment: It needs to be either set in some scope, like request or session or application and then it will be available to the JSP.  But as others have pointed out, avoid scriptlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a variable in JSP. You want to use `<jsp:useBean>` that gives you access to an **object**, then call getters and setters to this object.